# Where are the files pushed when you do "git push" when on branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

So I was on a branch and making a commit. I used `git push` instead of `git push --set-upstream origin branch"`and I didn't see the data on repository anywhere.

`git status` showed that data was pushed and I was up to date with remote but I couldn't see the data on the branch on GitLab.

Where should I check for the data that was pushed?

Comment: run any decent frontend and you should be able to see remote branches that are on that branch. Say `git log the-branch` or `gitk the-branch`.... and welcome to SO!.

Comment: And then, about gitlab... sure you checked _the right branch_?

Comment: If you checked the right branch in gitlab and the changes are not there, I can think of 2 possible explanations. First: are you sure the remote of your local repo is pointing to the right repo? Second: Did anybody push over your changes getting rid of them? If it's not either, then we could be talking about funkier stuff.

Answer (score 1):

With `git branch --show-current` or `git status` you will see the current branch where you have execute `git push` (assuming you haven't switched branches).

Now you know the name and can find the branch on GitLab.

Annotation: by default, `git push` only updates the corresponding branch on the remote. So, if you are checked out to the `master`-branch when you execute `git push`, then only the `master`-branch will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

(First, a brief note: `git push` pushes *commits*, not *files*.  The commits *contain* files, so you might think that there's no big deal / big difference here, but later, you'll find out that  it really is a big deal and a big difference.  That said, let's move on.)

The *full* answer is loaded with caveats, because:

- there's a `push.default` setting; and
- there are settings for `remote.remote.pushurl`, `remote.remote.push`, and so on

and these can all interact with exactly what you ran.

By default, however, as [SwissCodeMen mostly said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73227578/1256452), `git push` is equivalent to:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote || echo origin)
git push $remote $branch
```

**provided** that your Git version is at least 2.0 *and* you have not fiddled with all the other settings.  **But: if you have not set an upstream, this command would give you an error.**  You did not mention any errors occurring, so presumably you did not get an error, which means that either you're using an older Git version, or you already had an upstream set.  **So we're already in "something seems questionable" here territory.**  This means we need to know more about your actual situation; only you know the answers, so you'll have to read on.

The first two lines, that set `$branch` and `$remote`, just figure out which branch you're on—i.e., the branch name that `git status` would print, or that `git branch` would put an asterisk `*` next to, and then the name of the *remote* that corresponds to that branch.  If there isn't one yet—if the current branch has no upstream set—the remote name defaults to `origin`.

Next, since you didn't provide a refspec, Git goes on to look up the default push refspec *for* the remote.  That is, Git runs the internal equivalent of:

```
git config --get remote.$remote.push
```

By default, this isn't set, so this lookup fails; that tells Git to go on to query the setting of `push.default`:

```
git config --get push.default
```

This can be set to any of multiple values, including `matching` and `simple`.  The default in Git versions 2.0 and higher is `simple`, while the default in older Git versions is `matching`.

In `simple` mode, the `git push` gives you an *error* if:

- the upstream is not set yet; or
- the upstream setting's *branch* component does not match this branch name.

The *upstream setting* of a branch can be shown by two `git config --get` operations:

```
git config --get branch.$branch.remote
git config --get branch.$branch.merge
```

—either or both can fail, in which case the upstream isn't set—or, provided it's actually set, by:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}
```

If there's no upstream set, this produces, e.g.:

```
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'main'
```

#### The next section assumes `push.default` is `simple`

If you did have an upstream set, you don't need to run `git push --set-upstream`:

> I used `git push` instead of `git push --set-upstream origin branch`

The need for `--set-upstream`—the word *need* is a little too strong, but I'll leave it in without further explanation—is only there for the *first* `git push` from this branch.  It tells `git push` to run `git branch --set-upstream-to` if (after) the `git push` part succeeds, so that *future* `git push` operations *don't* need anything other than plain `git push`.  You can of course just run your own `git branch --set-upstream-to` command, but `--set-upstream` or just `-u` in the `git push` command is shorter to type, at least.

The purpose of the `simple` setting, which has been the default since Git version 2.0, is to make `git push` work the way normal humans (those who haven't been exposed to too much pre-2.0 Git like me ) expect.  Basically, you create a new branch `xyzbranch` in your own Git repository—which you cloned from GitLab or GitHub or Bitbucket, for instance—and then you use `git push --set-upstream origin xyzbranch` *once* and now the simple name `xyzbranch` "means" kind of the same thing in both clones and having your xyzbranch linked to their (GitLab's or whoever's) xyzbranch is sensible and everything Just Works.  Or rather, works as much as anything ever does in Git.

(This `simple` setting is good and you should use it.  That way you don't need to become a Git Guru.)

In this case, your `git push` was quite straightforward and it just updated the one branch name on your GitLab repository, and that's where you should find your commits.

#### What if you're not using `push.default` = `simple`?

Some systems come with Git 1.8, or even Git 1.7—anyway, some version predating Git 2.0.  Or, you might have used `git config` to change your `push.default` setting.

If you have `push.default` set to `matching`—and assuming no extra `remote.origin.push` setting—running:

```
git push origin
```

or anything equivalent (such as plain `git push` when the current branch's remote is `origin` or is unset) is nearly (but not quite) equivalent to running:

```
git push origin "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"
```

That is, for *each of your branch names*, your Git will `git push` to `origin`'s branch of the same name.

The key difference between `matching` and a literal `"refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` string is that if the Git repository over on the remote *lacks* some branch that you have, the `matching` style `git push` *won't push to it*.  That is, suppose you have branches `amazing`, `bracelet`, and `candy`, and they have branches `bracelet`, `candy`, and `drone`.  The *matching* names here are just `bracelet` and `candy` so those are the two that a "matching" style `git push` will push.

Note that even with `push.default` set to some other value, you can invoke the matching style of `git push` with `git push remote :`.  That is, by setting the (single) refspec argument to a single colon `:` character, you will get this `git push` behavior.

**This behavior is the default in ancient versions of Git.**  So if your system came with Git 1.7 or 1.8 for some reason, and you *didn't* tell it to *change* to `simple`, that's the kind of `git push` you ran.

#### What else to look at

Consider running:

```
git fetch --prune origin
git branch -vv
```

The initial `git fetch` command will have your Git call up whatever Git software answers at the stored URL for `origin`, ask them about their branch names, and update each of your remote-tracking names as appropriate.  The `--prune` flag tells your Git software that if they've *deleted* some branch name on their end, your Git should delete your *remote-tracking name*, i.e., your memory of their branch.  That is, if they had a branch `foolish` and you therefore have an `origin/foolish` but they then *deleted their `foolish`*, your Git should go ahead and delete your `origin/foolish` to match.

The `git branch` command will list out each of your own (local) branch names and, for each such name, whether there's an *upstream* set and if so, how your (local) branch compares to the upstream.  Since you've just updated all your remote-tracking names—the things you normally set up as upstreams in the first place—this will tell you how your branches correspond to theirs.

Remember that this is a two-step process:

- First, `git fetch` connects your Git to their Git, so that you can get the latest from them.  (Fetch and push are as close as Git gets to opposites here: fetch means "call them up and yank stuff from them", and push means "call them up and shove stuff at them".)
- Then, commands that work locally—`git log`, `git show`, and `git branch -vv` or `git branch -r` for instance—can now see your local memory of the other Git repository's branches, via the `origin/*` remote-tracking names.

I like to avoid `git pull` myself because `git pull` means: 1. run `git fetch`; then 2. run a second Git command to incorporate fetched commits, without stopping to let me look at what got fetched.  Pretty often, I like to run `git log` or some other command after `git fetch` gets me new stuff.  I want to know what that new stuff is, before I try to incorporate it into what *I* am working on.  The `git pull` command commits me—well, commits *you*, not me, because I don't use it—to trying to incorporate someone else's commits *before* you can even look at them.

Comment: Your answer are clear and realy nice, but always sooo fu**ing long 